# Auth between AWS API Gateway and Elastic Cloud hosted Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, authorization, aws-api-gateway

We're configuring an AWS API Gateway proxy in front of Elasticsearch deployed on Elastic Cloud (for throttling, usage plans, and various other reasons). In order to authenticate between the Gateway and ES, one idea is to configure an integration request on the API Gateway resource to add an [Authorization header](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/http-clients.html) with creds created in ES. Is this the best strategy? It seems inferior to IAM roles, but that option isn't available as they're not accessible for the ES instance (Elastic Cloud hosts our deployment on AWS, but it's not a resource under our control). The API Gateway itself will require an API key.

Comment: Why not using a simple nginx in front of ES cloud? https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx + https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-elasticsearch-better-together/

Comment: You mean instead of an AWS API Gateway? We want the API Usage plan options, throttling, logging and other metrics in the AWS system.

Comment: Maybe his helps then (even though it uses the AWS ES service and not ES cloud): https://www.freshlex.com/deploy_an_advanced_elasticsearch_proxy_with_lambda.html

Comment: See updated version of my Freshlex (site moved) post here: https://john.soban.ski/boto3-ec2-to-amazon-elasticsearch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert at Elasticsearch, but it sounds like you want to securely forward a request from API gateway to another REST web service. Because Elasticsearch is an external REST web service to AWS, you will not have access to IAM roles. I had a similar integration to another cloud rest service (not elasticsearch) will do my best to review the tools in AWS that are available to complete the request.

*One idea is to configure an integration request on the API Gateway resource to add an Authorization header with creds created in ES. Is this the best strategy?*

This is the most straightforward strategy. In API Gateway, you can map custom headers in the Integration Request. This is where you will map your Authorization header for Elastic Search.

Similarly you can map your Authorization Header as a "Stage Variable" which will make it easier to maintain if the Authorization Header will change across different Elasticsearch environments.

In both strategies, you are storing your Authorization Header in API Gateway. Since the request to Elasticsearch should be HTTPS, the data will be secure in transit. This [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229629) has more information about storing credentials in API Gateway.

From MikeD@AWS: *There are currently no known issues with using stage variables to manage credentials; however, stage variables were not explicitly designed to be a secure mechanism for credentials management. Like all API Gateway configuration information, stage variables are protected using standard AWS permissions and policies and they are encrypted when transmitted over the wire. Internally, stage variables are treated as confidential customer information.*

I think this applies to your question. You can store the Authorization Header in the API Gateway Proxy, however you have to acknowledge that API Gateway Configuration information was not explicitly designed for sensitive information. That being said, there are no known issues with doing so. This approach is the most straightforward to configure if you are willing to assume that risk.

**What is a more "AWS" Approach?**

An "AWS" approach would be to use the services designed for the function. For example, using the [Key Management Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/overview.html) to store your Elasticsearch Authorization Header.

Similarly to the [tutorial](https://www.freshlex.com/deploy_an_advanced_elasticsearch_proxy_with_lambda.html) referenced in the comments, you will want to forward your request from API Gateway to Lambda. You will be responsible for creating the HTTPS request to Elasticsearch in the language of your choice. There are several tutorials on this but this is the official [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html). AWS provides blueprints as a template to start a Lambda Function. The Blueprint `https-request` will work.

Once the request is being forwarded from API Gateway to Lambda, configure the authorization header for the Lambda request as an [Environment Variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html) and implement [Environment Variable Encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html#env_encrypt). This is a secure recommended way to store sensitive data, such as the Elasticsearch authorization header.

This approach will require more configuration but uses AWS services for intended purposes.

**My Opinion**: I initially used the first approach (Authorization Headers in API Gateway) to authenticate with a dev instance because it was quick and easy, but as I learned more I decided the second approach was more aligned with the [AWS Well Architected Framework](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/AWS_Well-Architected_Framework.pdf)